# Множество динамических параметров в get запросе

Tags: javascript, express, route, router

Как реализовать получение через get запрос любого кол-ва **разных** параметров?
Пример строки запроса:

```
/api/users/search?firstName=iv&lastName=cat
/api/cars/search?color=red
```

Comment: Вопрос не совсем понятен...

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Для гет запроса в хендлере пишется строка - шаблон по которому парсится запрос и достаются параметры. Например `router.get('/:instanceId', (req, res, next) => {});`. В данном примере параметр `instanceId`. Моя пробелма заключается в том, что мне нужно одним таким хендлером обрабатывать гет запрос в котором может быть любое кол-во параметров с разными именами.

Comment: `var url = require('url');
var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;`
Код нагуген за минуту на enSO.

Comment: как это совместить с express? можете дать более детальный ответ?

Answer (score 0):

Для доступа к query-параметрам запроса в express существует встроенный объект *request.query* который содержит пары ключ-значение этих параметров. Например, для запроса вида */api/users/search?firstName=iv&lastName=cat* он будет иметь вид:

```
{
  firstName: 'iv',
  lastName: 'cat',
}
```

Если запрос отправлен без параметров, то в request.query будет храниться пустой объект.

Вот небольшой пример использования объекта request.query для динамического формирования запроса к базе данных:

```
export const oldSetFilters = (filters: {[key: string]: string }): string => {
    let filtersString = '';

    if ( filters && Object.keys(filters).length ) {
        for (const key in filters) {
            filtersString += `${ key }=${ filters[key] } AND `;
        }
    }

    filtersString = `WHERE ${filtersString.substring(0, filtersString.length - 5)}`;
    return filtersString;
};
```

Хэндлер маршрута:

```
app.route('/v2/:table')
                .get( async (req, res) => {
                    try {
                        const filters = oldSetFilters(req.query);

                        const rows = await db.sqlGetRequest(
                            `SELECT * FROM ${req.params.table} ${filters};`
                        );

                        logger.info(`${req.params.table} were sent to admin`);
                        res.status(200).send(rows);

                    } catch (error) {
                        logger.error(`${req.params.table} sending to admin failed`, error);
                        res.status(500).send(error);
                    }
                })
```

Надеюсь, это поможет.

Comment: блин, выпиливал из кода объявления типов, а потом в профиле увидел что вы работаете с ангуляром и стало быть знаете typescript)

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ, это не совсем то что мне нужно было. Думаю, я плохо выразился при написании вопроса. Саму логику фильтрации я реализовал, но я не мог связать её с запросом. Я не понимал как получить параметры из запроса, чтобы потом передать их для обработки. Решение оказалось элементарным - в expresse все параметры парсятся и помещаются в request.query. [Источник](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то ваш хендлер ожидает получить строку отличную от тех, что описаны в вопросе. Откуда у вас в первом примере берутся `filters`? во втором примере откуда берется `table` в логере?

Comment: по поводу table - конечно там должно быть req.params.table. сейчас поправлю. спасибо. по поводу filters - из кастомной функции setFilters, которая описана абзацем выше и парсит req.query - тот самый объект с параметрами запроса, который вы тоже нашли в документации самостоятельно

Comment: по поводу ожидаемой строки - конечно отличную. это абстрактный пример. вам переписать для вашего конкретного случая или вы поняли принцип?

Comment: Все что мне нужно было это получить параметры из запросов. Напишите просто в начале ответа про req.query и можете оставить всё остальное, я засчитаю как ответ на вопрос. Еще раз извиняюсь что плохо сформулировал вопрос.